# error en if al comparar un diccionario con un entero

Tags: python

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

tengo el siguiente error en el codigo

```
, line 41, in <module>
if sum1 < 10.5:
```

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'dict' and 'float'

Answer (score 0):

`sum1` está declarado como diccionario, o sea, es un contenedor de múltiples pares (llave, valor).

No necesitas un diccionario para guardar **un** promedio. Simplemente elimina la declaración

```
sum1 = {}
```

y reemplaza

```
sum1 = sum(...) / 3
```

**Nota**

Normalmente mis respuestas son de código completo y comprobadas. Como pusistes una imagen del código, no me voy a dar el trabajo de copiarlo para certificar que mi respuesta sea correcta.

Comment: pero al hacer eso , no se va agregar el promedio en el archivo json?

Comment: Esa es otra pregunta. Recuerda publicar el código como texto para que otros puedan copia-pegar-y-probarlo.